# What's it called when someone is crafty and resourceful and creates a solution to a particular obstacle?

Tags: single-word-requests, adjectives

What's it called when someone is crafty and resourceful and creates a solution to a particular obstacle? I saw it somewhere online and blanked on it when I had a golden opportunity. Anyone got me?

Comment: *Problem-solver* would work, but I'm afraid there are far too many candidates here.

Comment: Is there a particular context you have in mind? A sample sentence perhaps?

Answer (score 3):

The first that come to mind are:

- witty
- clever
- thrifty
- ingenious
- innovative

Answer (score 1):

the word *Sly* perhaps is what you seek.